# Node js microservice

Tags: node.js, spring, microservices

Can anyone please tell how to consume a node js based microservice from spring based web application?can restful API be the best choice to be used by the application to message the microservices based on nodejs ?

Comment: Rest APIs are straightforward and could be a good choice if you are familiar with it and in that case you can just start working on it. There are also some other alternatives like grpc https://grpc.io/ or websocket

Comment: Thank you for the response.it helped!

Comment: Thank you for the response.it helped!

Answer (score -1):

[seneca](http://senecajs.org) is not based on spring but can quick build restful API